# GPX visualiser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, gpx

I'm trying to write an HTML page where the user can upload a GPX file and it is then converted into a series of points on a map, using OpenStreetMap. What is the best way to do this? (Using JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

I think Leaflet should work for you.  https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/
There is a plugin `qgis2web` that should generate the initial HTML for you.

- https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/leaflet_maps_with_qgis2leaf.html